# Removing some pages in a given template

Tags: thesis

I have the following thesis template to work out:

- [METU Thesis template](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5572bfd7c9d1b5013f5488c8),

and since I will not use any tables and figures in my thesis, I want to remove the pages titled with "List of Tables" and "List of Figures". There are some definitions etc. in the "metu.cls" file but I don't understand what to change there and how. Can anyone explain what to do?

Comment: What you want to get rid of is activated by `\begin{preliminaries}` and `\end{preliminaries}`. It seems ok if you comment these two lines but I am not sure. Search for `lof` and `lot` in the `metu.cls` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably sufficient to comment (or remove) the lines 1029 and 1030 of metu.cls (`\listoftables` and `\listoffigures`).